# SSH authentication failure from 4g network

Tags: ssh

I use JuiceSSH to connect to my server via my Android device. If the device is connected via Wi-Fi, all goes smoothly. But if I connect via 4g network, then I get `Authentication failure` error. Why? I couldn't find any solution so far. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Run server in debugging mode (`sshd -d`) and see why authentication fails.

Comment: Where is "your server" located from a network perspective? It is in your network or is it just one server on the Internet?

Comment: @Robert It's on my home network, the router is forwarding correctly and I have static IP. As I said, if I join via Wifi, whatever wifi, it connects without problem. But via 4g network not.

Comment: For example, now I am on holiday, if my android device is connected to the hotel wifi, I can ssh into my server. From 4g no.

Comment: Which mobile network provider do you use? Because the only reason for this behavior I can imagine based on your description is that your mobile network provider is blocking/redirecting SSH traffic. I would try to use a non-standard ssh port for your server instead. See if this makes a difference. Also check the ssh server log (of capture the traffic via tshark) if you really had a connection to it.

Comment: @Robert Usually, I am on Tele2, from The Netherlands. Now on Italian Vodafone, same story. Thanks for the port suggestion, I will check it up.